# Reference fields in subform query (ms Access)

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form, `frmResults`, which contains a subform control, `frmResultsSub`.

`frmResultsSub` is a subform control which contains a query instead of a form. In other words, its SourceObject property is set to the query, "`Query.qrySearch`"

Is there any way I can reference the fields of this query to e.g. to centre text or change field width?

I've tried these statements in the Open Event for `frmResults`, but neither was successful:

```
Me!frmResultsSub.fldA.Width = 600
Me.frmResultsSub.fldA.Width = 600
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference the *fldA* field in the query the same as you would if it were the name of a textbox on a form contained in that *frmResultsSub* subform control.

Put this in *On Load* and verify it shows you the field name instead of triggering an error ...

```vb
MsgBox Me!frmResultsSub!fldA.name
```

Once you have that working correctly, you can work with the column's properties.  During *On Load*, adjust its `ColumnWidth` property to change its width ...

```vb
Me!frmResultsSub!fldA.ColumnWidth = 600
```

That should allow you to set the width.  But you also mentioned text alignment, and I don't see how to do that for a query column unless you create an actual form based on the query.

Comment: Many thanks for everyone's help here. As above, Me!SubFqrySearchHLA!DonorAx.ColumnWidth = 600, worked in the On Load event (forgot to adjust field/form names - thanks for seeing through the confusion!). All field widths can now be customised. What I should do is put the query output into a continuous form which will give much more format/customisation/presentation possibilities. The query, however, yields variable numbers of fields (the Wizard sets controls up according to the last run query). I could create a new continuous form for each display through VBA, or there might be an easier way.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `Me.frmResultsSub.Form.fldA.Width = 600`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can adjust column width on a query using VBA. You can however solve your problem using one of those methods:

- create a form (`AutoForm` is ok) and make its default view as Datasheet. then use that form as the source of your subform control. that will be visually identical to your current solution.
- use a listBox instead of a subform. It's quite versatile and you can easily set the listbox `rowSource` to any SQL statement. You will have to handle sync with main form data but it is very simple.